# OAuth2 token request via post: no result, no error, no network message

Tags: angular

In my Ng App I should implement the Login / Authentication part via OAuth2. As usual, my app should obtain a token and then use it. First of all, I tried to obtained the token via Postman with the credential I attach, to check the correctness of this credentials. All works, I see correctly the token.

Then, I tried to obtain the same token via Angular by the following code:

SERVICE

```
//See the attach image for a,b,c,d,e
constructor(private http: HttpClient) {

    formData = new URLSearchParams();
    formData.set('grant_type', 'password');
    formData.set('username', b);
    formData.set('password', c)
    httpOptions = {
        headers: new HttpHeaders({
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf8',
            'Authorization': 'Basic' + ' ' + btoa('d:e')
        })
    };
    url = a;
}

login(): Observable<string> {

    return this.http.post<string>(url, formData.toString(), httpOptions)
    .pipe(map(ar =>  ar.toString()))
}
```

CALL

```
console.log(this.authService.login());
```

But nothing appears. No error in IDE, no error in Chrome Developer panel, no connection message in Network tab of this panel. Why is this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to subscribe to the observable returned by the HttpClient methods in order for the request to be sent, and in order to get the result.

The HttpClient in angular uses rxjs Observables to model asynchronous operations. Be sure to understand the concepts it implies.

See https://angular.io/guide/http for more information.